# FFMpeg drawtext not working in my code

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay a text on existing movie using `FFMpeg`. Overlaying of an image works perfectly, but failed to drawtext. My code is as below.

```
GeneralUtils.checkForPermissionsMAndAbove(RecordVideo.this, true);
LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
String[] complexCommand = {
    "ffmpeg", "-i", FilePath, "-vf",
    "drawtext=text='Hello Dev..':"
        + "fontsize=24:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=w-tw:y=h-th",
    FilePath1};
vk.run(complexCommand , StorageDIR , getApplicationContext());
```

I am getting error as follows

```
ffmpeg version git-2016-10-26-efa89a8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg 

developers
  built with gcc 4.9 (GCC) 20140827 (prerelease)
ffmpeg4android 3.22_00_full_LM322 
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402.avi'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'drawtext=text='Hello Dev..':fontsize=24:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=w-tw:y=h-th'.
Reading option '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402_1.avi' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402.avi.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402.avi.
Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Probing mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 score:100 size:2048
Probing mp3 score:1 size:2048
Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
type: 70797466 'ftyp' parent:'root' sz: 24 8 3096055
ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
type: 7461646d 'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 3093790 32 3096055
type: 766f6f6d 'moov' parent:'root' sz: 2241 3093822 3096055
type: 6468766d 'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 2233
time scale = 1000
type: 61746475 'udta' parent:'moov' sz: 52 116 2233
type: 4e4c4453 'SDLN' parent:'udta' sz: 16 8 44
type: 64726d73 'smrd' parent:'udta' sz: 16 24 44
type: 61746d73 'smta' parent:'udta' sz: 12 40 44
type: 6174656d 'meta' parent:'moov' sz: 119 168 2233
type: 726c6468 'hdlr' parent:'meta' sz: 33 8 111
ctype=  (0x00000000)
stype= mdta
type: 7379656b 'keys' parent:'meta' sz: 43 41 111
type: 74736c69 'ilst' parent:'meta' sz: 35 84 111
type: 01000000 '' parent:'ilst' sz: 27 8 27
lang "   " tag "com.android.version" value "7.0" atom "" 7 3
type: 6b617274 'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 1023 287 2233
type: 64686b74 'tkhd' parent:'trak' sz: 92 8 1015
type: 6169646d 'mdia' parent:'trak' sz: 923 100 1015
type: 6468646d 'mdhd' parent:'mdia' sz: 32 8 915
type: 726c6468 'hdlr' parent:'mdia' sz: 44 40 915
ctype=  (0x00000000)
stype= vide
type: 666e696d 'minf' parent:'mdia' sz: 839 84 915
type: 64686d76 'vmhd' parent:'minf' sz: 20 8 831
type: 666e6964 'dinf' parent:'minf' sz: 36 28 831
type: 66657264 'dref' parent:'dinf' sz: 28 8 28
type url  size 12
Unknown dref type 0x08206c7275 size 12
type: 6c627473 'stbl' parent:'minf' sz: 775 64 831
type: 64737473 'stsd' parent:'stbl' sz: 171 8 767
size=155 4CC= avc1/0x31637661 codec_type=0
type: 43637661 'avcC' parent:'stsd' sz: 34 8 69
type: 70736170 'pasp' parent:'stsd' sz: 16 42 69
type: 726c6f63 'colr' parent:'stsd' sz: 19 58 69
nclx: pri 1 trc 1 matrix 1 full 0
type: 73747473 'stts' parent:'stbl' sz: 304 179 767
track[0].stts.entries = 36
sample_count=1, sample_duration=5942
.
sample_count=2, sample_duration=5401
type: 73737473 'stss' parent:'stbl' sz: 24 483 767
keyframe_count = 2
type: 7a737473 'stsz' parent:'stbl' sz: 188 507 767
sample_size = 0 sample_count = 42
type: 63737473 'stsc' parent:'stbl' sz: 52 695 767
track[0].stsc.entries = 3
type: 6f637473 'stco' parent:'stbl' sz: 28 747 767
AVIndex stream 0, sample 0, offset 831f, dts 0, size 212746, distance 0, keyframe 1
.
AVIndex stream 0, sample 41, offset 2e28a5, dts 221935, size 68753, distance 11, keyframe 0
type: 6b617274 'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 931 1310 2233
type: 64686b74 'tkhd' parent:'trak' sz: 92 8 923
type: 6169646d 'mdia' parent:'trak' sz: 831 100 923
type: 6468646d 'mdhd' parent:'mdia' sz: 32 8 823
type: 726c6468 'hdlr' parent:'mdia' sz: 44 40 823
ctype=  (0x00000000)
stype= soun
type: 666e696d 'minf' parent:'mdia' sz: 747 84 823
type: 64686d73 'smhd' parent:'minf' sz: 16 8 739
type: 666e6964 'dinf' parent:'minf' sz: 36 24 739
type: 66657264 'dref' parent:'dinf' sz: 28 8 28
type url  size 12
Unknown dref type 0x08206c7275 size 12
type: 6c627473 'stbl' parent:'minf' sz: 687 60 739
type: 64737473 'stsd' parent:'stbl' sz: 91 8 679
size=75 4CC= mp4a/0x6134706d codec_type=1
audio channels 2
version =0, isom =1
type: 73647365 'esds' parent:'stsd' sz: 39 8 39
MPEG-4 description: tag=0x03 len=25
MPEG-4 description: tag=0x04 len=17
esds object type id 0x40
MPEG-4 description: tag=0x05 len=2
Specific MPEG-4 header len=2
mp4a config channels 2 obj 2 ext obj 0 sample rate 48000 ext sample rate 0
type: 73747473 'stts' parent:'stbl' sz: 32 99 679
track[1].stts.entries = 2
sample_count=1, sample_duration=1024
sample_count=113, sample_duration=1024
type: 7a737473 'stsz' parent:'stbl' sz: 476 131 679
sample_size = 0 sample_count = 114
type: 63737473 'stsc' parent:'stbl' sz: 52 607 679
track[1].stsc.entries = 3
type: 6f637473 'stco' parent:'stbl' sz: 28 659 679
AVIndex stream 1, sample 0, offset 20, dts 0, size 682, distance 0, keyframe 1
AVIndex stream 1, sample 1, offset 2ca, dts 1024, size 683, distance 0, keyframe 1
.
AVIndex stream 1, sample 99, offset 28939d, dts 101376, size 682, distance 0, keyframe 1
.
AVIndex stream 1, sample 113, offset 28b8f2, dts 115712, size 683, distance 0, keyframe 1
on_parse_exit_offset=3096055
rfps: 16.500000 0.014060
rfps: 16.583333 0.003530
rfps: 16.666667 0.000000
rfps: 16.666667 0.000000
rfps: 16.750000 0.003470
rfps: 16.750000 0.003470
rfps: 16.833333 0.013939
rfps: 50.000000 0.000001
rfps: 50.000000 0.000001
Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 3096055 bytes read:35009 seeks:1 nb_streams:2
nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
stream 0, sample 0, dts 0
.
stream 1, sample 47, dts 1002667
nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
All info found
stream 0: start_time: 0.000 duration: 2.526
stream 1: start_time: 0.000 duration: 2.432
format: start_time: 0.000 duration: 2.520 bitrate=9828 kb/s
After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 246313 bytes read:281290 seeks:2 frames:48
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-07-10T08:44:06.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:00:02.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9828 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng), 1, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 9551 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 16.63 fps, 16.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-10T08:44:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-10T08:44:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle

Successfully opened the file.
    Parsing a group of options: output file /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402_1.avi.
    Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument drawtext=text='Hello Dev..':fontsize=24:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=w-tw:y=h-th.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an output file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReporterLive/VID_10072018141402_1.avi.
    Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
    Successfully opened the file.
    No such filter: 'drawtext'
    Error opening filters!
    Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
    Statistics: 281290 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong ? I want to do it in the simplest form.

Comment: Your ffmpeg build does not have drawtext filter. Get one of the builds from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please tell how to add drawtext filter to FFMpeg. I have downloaded ffmpeg4android from here only.

Comment: From Cygwin i also tried ./configure --enable-filter=drawtext --enable-libfreetype.. but it says gcc is unable to create an executable file.

Comment: The first link has drawtext in it : https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android/releases/tag/v0.3.4

Comment: I have downloaded pre built binaries from your said url and i got 3 folders in it named 1. armeabi-v7a, 2. armeabi-v7a-neon, 3. x86. Now where to put these folders in my existing project. I had added ffmpeg4android_lib as Import Module in my project. Please guide..